# mysql dump issue

Tags: mysql

mysql gives me the syntax error with the following line... i dont know what is wrong with this...

```
mysqldump -u root -p root mydatabase > dumpfile.sql
```

i am using windows vista...

plz help here..
thnx..

Comment: Please add the error message.

Comment: It sounds like you might be specifying some criteria for the dump and there is a problem with that. Can you post it exactly as you are calling it or is this it?

Comment: Also are you trying to run this within the mysql shell? mysqldump is a stand alone application and should be run as such.

Comment: well i am running this command in mysql-command-prompt on windows vista...

Comment: Ok that sounds like the problem. See the answer I posted below. But you are running it from the wrong spot. mysqldump is a standalone application so just run it from the mysql bin folder where the app should be.

Comment: I might add that you should have provided that information from the start - a lot of effort would have been saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are running this from the normal command line and not within the mysql command line. So like this:

```
C:\[path to mysqldump app] > mysqldump -u root -p root mydatabase > dumpfile.sql
```

not

```
mysql > mysqldump -u root -p root mydatabase > dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution.

Comment: Right. mysqldump is a separate program, not a command to use in a mysql client.

Comment: hmmm... when i run the following command:

C:\\[path to mysqldump app] > mysqldump -u root -p root mydatabase > dumpfile.sql

then i was asked for the password when i enter the "root" as a password it gave me an error:
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password yes) when trying to connect.

but when i remove the password from the command and ran it i was asked for the password which i entered "root"; was a successful run...

C:\\[path to mysqldump app] > mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > dumpfile.sql

thnx aloadz guyz... really appreciate it...

Comment: First off check @Pekka answer below as to why it asked you for the password again even though you specified. You have a space between -p and the password. Remove that and it will fix the problem of it asking you again. As to your other question not sure exactly why that would be.

Answer (score 3):

The `-p` part is the problem. From the [manual](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mysqldump/):

> The password to use when connecting to the server. **If you use the
>              short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option
>              and the password.** If you omit the password value following the
>              --password or -p option on the command line, you are prompted for
>              one.

Try

```
mysqldump -u root -proot mydatabase > dumpfile.sql
```

But in the future, please ask a proper question including any error messages you get (you certainly got one in this case) so people don't have to guess.

Comment: I usually also omit the space between -u and username to get password and user consistent. But the error message should be pretty easy - cannot connect user root without password or something like that.

Comment: @Jamal and at which point does that error come up? Surely not when calling `mysqldump`?

Comment: i am running this from mysql command prompt on windows vista... mysql version is 5.1.45

Comment: @Jamal no no no, mysqldump is a separate program. You run it from the normal Windows command line.