# dump file in mysql 5.0.88 issue

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to make a dump file of one of the database in mysql server 5.0.88 but I am getting an `Access is denied.` in response.

This is what I am doing:
I am using command prompt of windows 7 and specifies the path to the **mysqldump** application and run the command to make the dump file. Here is my complete command:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin>mysqldump -u root -ppassword mydatabase > dumpfile.sql;
```

I've gone through the thread [mysql dump issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400390/mysql-dump-issue) thread already. 
Could someone please help me understand what is going on here and why am I not able to create a dump file?
I've been trying it for quite sometime but still ain't able to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: post the whole error, and are you sure you can write files in that directory ?

Comment: @nos: The only error I get is **Access is denied.** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error you are seeing is like:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access is denied for user 'root'@
```

then the issue is with mysql authentication.  (There's no point in addressing that, unless that's the error you are seeing.)

If you are getting an error:

```
Error 5: Access is denied
```

then the issue is with file system permissions  (i.e you don't have permissions to write the specified file to the specified directory.)

It's not good practice to write the mysqldump file into the mysql bin directory.

The resolution to this would be to write the file to a directory where you do have permissions .e.g.

```
> mysqldump -u root -ppassword mydatabase >C:\users\spencer7593\mydatabase.sql
```

Comment: Yeah, i wasnt allowed to write in the folder I was trying to write it to. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have write permissions in the `MySQL Server 5.0` directory? "Access is denied" is a cmd.exe error message, not a MySQL one.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have rights to write to the folder I was trying to write the dump file. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has higher security for writting under System Folders that includes Program Files folder. Try saving to some other drive... other than `C:\` Something like

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword mydatabase > D:\dumpfile.sql;
```

If you have to start your command prompt as Administrator. See here https://superuser.com/questions/33373/windows-7-you-dont-have-permissions-to-save-in-this-folder